# Show that is $\upsilon$ is an eigenvector of the matrices A and AB

Tags: proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

(assume invertibility)

Show that is $\upsilon$ is an eigenvector of the matrices A and AB with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda \neq 0$, $\mu$ respectively, then $\upsilon$ is also a corresponding eigenvector of B with corresponding eigenvalue $\frac{\mu}{\lambda}$.

What I have so far:
$$A\upsilon=\lambda\upsilon$$
$$A^{-1}A\upsilon=A^{-1}\lambda\upsilon$$
$$\upsilon=\lambda A^{-1}\upsilon$$
$$\frac{1}{\lambda}\upsilon=A^{-1}\upsilon$$

$$AB\upsilon=\mu\upsilon$$
$$A^{-1}AB\upsilon=A^{-1}\mu\upsilon$$
$$B\upsilon=\mu A^{-1}\upsilon$$
$$B\upsilon=\frac{\mu}{\lambda}\upsilon$$

Is this enough to prove the statement or am I missing anything?

Comment: How do you know that $A$ is invertible?

Comment: Wherever the question comes from, your reasoning seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is right, since you seem to assume invertibility of $A$.

Without invertibility of $A$, the statement is wrong: Take
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \ 
B = \pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},  \ v = \pmatrix{1\\0},
$$
then $Av = v$, $AB=0$, but $v$ is not an eigenvector of $B$.